# 7-speed cassette on an 11-speed freehub

Tags: cassette, freewheel

Is it possible to use an SRAM cassette PG 730 7-speed cassette with a Mavic FTS-X freehub? According to the spec, no spacer is required for an 11-speed cassette and for 9/10 speed version a spacer is required. I'm a bit confused since the manual is kind of vague.

Answer (score 2):

Some good guidelines are [here](http://sheldonbrown.com/speeds.html), courtesy of Sheldon Brown.

Assuming you have the right freehub body for Shimano/SRAM-style cassettes on the FTS-X, you just (probably) need a 4.5mm spacer behind the cassette.